# Closing GitHub issues on non master branch

Tags: github

I have modified the default branch of a particular project to `develop`, instead of the default `master`. However, commits to the `develop` branch including the [closure messages](https://help.github.com/articles/closing-issues-via-commit-messages/) are not closing issues (even though the automatic linkage between issue and commit is functioning).

Do I need to somehow explicitly link issues to this branch? The documentation only refers to the default branch.